# Unexpected server response using sockets and STMP TLS

Tags: php, sockets, smtp, tls1.2, starttls

This is my first time I do anything with SMTP, so please have patience if I am doing something terribly wrong here :) **Normally, I just use PHPMailer, but this is not an option in this case.**

I am trying to send an email to people in a mailing list. I am using fsockopen and I need to use a TLS connection to do this.

**This is what I do:**

- $conn = fsockopen() // my details goes in there, it connects.
- HELO myhost.com (fwrite)
- STARTTLS (fwrite)
- stream_socket_enable_crypto( $conn, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT );
- HELO myhost.com (fwrite)
- AUTH LOGIN (fwrite)
- base64_encoded USERNAME (fwrite)
- base64_encoded PASSWORD (fwrite)
- MAIL FROM: (fwrite)
- RCPT TO:; (fwrite)
- DATA (fwrite)
- A string with all my headers (fwrite)
- fclose($conn);

**This is where something goes wrong**

After using an encypted connection I can't seem to successfully read the server response. For example, when trying to read the response by using `fgets($conn,1024)` after my authentication it takes forever and then finally I will get a highly encrypted code not being able to look for response "235" (to make sure my authentication succeeded).

And then when I write MAIL FROM my response will look like this:

```
.0.0 SMTP server ready
```

While I think I would want something like this:

```
250 2.0.0
```

Something gets wrong, but I don't know why. I hope any of all you experts out there can help me go to the bottom with this  problem :)

Thanks in advance!

**SOLVED IT**

In case anyone else runs into this problem.

**This order works**

- $conn = fsockopen() // my details goes in there, it connects.
- EHLO myhost.com (fwrite)
- STARTTLS (fwrite)
- stream_socket_enable_crypto( $conn, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT );
- EHLO myhost.com (fwrite)
- AUTH LOGIN (fwrite)
- base64_encoded USERNAME (fwrite)
- base64_encoded PASSWORD (fwrite)
- MAIL FROM: (fwrite)
- RCPT TO:; (fwrite)
- DATA (fwrite)
- A string with all my headers (fwrite)
- fclose($conn);

Between every call I added the following:

```
stream_set_timeout($conn, 300);
set_time_limit(310);
```

Suddenly I got the expected replies from the server and the mail was successfully sent.

Comment: Why can't you use PHPMailer ?

Comment: Well, we're making changes to a custom engine that has been working great so far.. I was thinking that it would take longer time to change it all to run with PHPMailer than just start the TLS connection in what we already got. Now I am so into it, so I don't want to drop it. I want to know what goes wrong as well ;)

Comment: I'd cut your losses and use PHPMailer; weigh up the time spent altering your code to use PHPMailer against how long it will take you to re-write the same functionality yourself. Aside from that I wish you the best of luck with it; I wasted days trying to do this and in the end gave up and used PHPMailer instead.

Comment: @SteJ, I was just about to abanndon the ship and seek shelter under PHPMailer when I got it to work. Edited my post above in case you (or anyone else) is interested.

Comment: That's great - Good to hear you've got it sorted! That's certainly useful info; if only this post were a few months ago I would have saved myself from having the additional dependency in my code.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED IT**

In case anyone else runs into this problem.

**This order works**

- $conn = fsockopen() // my details goes in there, it connects.
- EHLO myhost.com (fwrite)
- STARTTLS (fwrite)
- stream_socket_enable_crypto( $conn, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT );
- EHLO myhost.com (fwrite)
- AUTH LOGIN (fwrite)
- base64_encoded USERNAME (fwrite)
- base64_encoded PASSWORD (fwrite)
- MAIL FROM: (fwrite)
- RCPT TO:; (fwrite)
- DATA (fwrite)
- A string with all my headers (fwrite)
- fclose($conn);

Between every call I added the following:

```
stream_set_timeout($conn, 300);
set_time_limit(310);
```

Suddenly I got the expected replies from the server and the mail was successfully sent.

– entiendoNull